What is the difference between Norton's dome experiment and $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= 6x^{\frac{1}{3}}$?
Suppose a particle at $x=0$ (such that the initial speed is also 0) obeys the equation of motion:
$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}=6(x(t))^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
I see that both the trajectories : $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=t^3$ satisfy this equation of motion. Hence the trajectory isn't deterministic, given the initial conditions.
Does this example demonstrate the same point as Norton's dome, or is Norton's dome something more?
Also, Wikipedia says that Norton's dome requires discontinuities in the force and the force to be an indeterminate form, while this example does not require those things. Why is that?

There are any number of problems you could invent that have this behaviour. The advantage of Norton's dome is its shape causes known physics to induce such a problem. (Mind you, I suppose you could in theory build an "impose $F=6mx^{1/3}$ machine" to the same effect.)

@J.G. thanks.... so i think there is no difference here from a mathematical standpoint. As a side question, do we know that standard model Euler lagrange equations don't have this behavior?

I forgot to mention the other advantage is the "it does move after all" case with Norton's dome has to pick an arbitrary direction, breaking the rotational symmetry. Are you asking about the Standard Model in particle physics? If so, you might want to post a fresh question about that, concerning whether suitable choices of currents "put in by hand" can cause a behaviour similar to the dome's.

@J.G. thanks. the arbitrary direction thing is intriguing. And yes, i meant the standard model of particle physics. Books say that Euler Lagrange equations are non deterministic when the Hessian matrix has determinant zero. But these differential equations show that that isn't sufficient. I feel these cases happen when the acceleration is determined as a function of the initial conditions (which is what the Hessian matrix checks), but jerk or some higher derivative are left undetermined as a function of the initial conditions.

I've not studied this but I note the following from Wiki article on Norton's dome: "However, the same argument applied to the usual kinds of domes (e.g., a hemisphere) fails, because a ball launched with just the right energy to reach the top and stay there would actually take infinite time to do so." You should check whether your example has this behaviour.

@AndrewSteane yes. I think it satisfies that test, because I'm not using domes and directly using a force equation

Your example seems very much like Norton's Dome. You can turn yours into a dome by changing your equation to $\frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2}=6(r(t))^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Norton used a constant force instead of one that varies with time.


Wikipedia says that Norton's dome requires discontinuities in the force and the force to be an indeterminate form, while this example does not require those things. Why is that?

Assuming the particle has zero total energy, your ODE is equivalent to
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 3 x^{2/3}.
$$
This ODE fails to satisfy the requirements of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which would guarantee existence and uniqueness of local solutions, since the right-hand side is not Lipschitz continuous in $x$ at $x = 0$. (This occurs because the derivative of $f(x) = 3 x^{2/3}$ diverges at $x = 0$.)
The "Norton's dome" ODE has the same mathematical problem, so the indeterminacy of this example and the Norton's dome example are closely related.  It seems to me that your example shows that the basic Wikipedia arguments are, if not inaccurate, at least in need of some refinement.

It is not necessary to assume zero total energy to find the problem with the Lipschitz condition you pointed out. Just pass from the second order Newtonian equation to a first order system of a pair of ODEs by adding the new variable $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. This first order system in $X=(x,v)$ is in normal form but the right hand side is not Lipschitz at every $(0,v_0)$.

The Norton Ansatz for the force is
$$ F=m\,k\,s^{1/2}$$
thus , you obtain  with
$$ U=-m\,g\,\frac{dF}{ds}=F\quad\Rightarrow\\
z(s)=-\frac 23\frac{s^{2/3}\,k}{g} $$
where s is the generalized coordinate
your Ansatz for the force is
$$ F=m\,k\,s^{1/3} $$
and
$$z(s)=-\frac 34\frac{s^{4/3}\,k}{g}$$
the shape is still Norton Dome

Norton EOM
$$\ddot s-k\sqrt{s}=0$$
